# Caching - updating multiple js files with query string at one time

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, caching

I'm working with MVC and we want to stop browsers from loading our old .js/.css files. Most of the 'net says use a query string on the end of the .js file. So, in one View, I've done that like this:

```
@section scripts
{
     <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Person/people_list.js?" + System.DateTime.Now)"></script>
}
```

So far so good, this works great. Caching testing behaves as I would like.

Here's my question - We have a lot of these script tags over several different files. We want all of our .js/.css to use this pattern. I was wondering if there was a way to add code somewhere that would update all of these script tags to add the query string. (Like maybe in the Shared Folder's Layout.cshtml?)  Or, should I just go update every single one in each view manually?

Thanks

Comment: you can set expires header for these static files so that the browsers stop loading oldjs and css files what web server are you using? are you delivering these files from a cdn ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the replies so far! We are using IIS. A friend suggested editing the web server's options like this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ForcingAnUpdateOfACachedJavaScriptFileInIIS.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should probably switch to using bundling and minification.  It will autogenerate the query string value for you any time you change one of the files.  Your code as is, will never allow the resources to be cached because the DateTime.Now will never be the same between calls (Unless you do output caching as well).

Here's an article on how to do it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification and although it talks about MVC 4/.NET 4.5, you can get the bundling and minification stuff from nuget for earlier versions of .NET and can use it on older webforms websites, it just wasn't built in.

Also for easier debugging, and faster/smaller production files, you should include your styles like:

```
@section styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/content/home")
}
```

and your javascript like:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}
```

This allows you to switch between having individually included scripts and styles in debug, and fully combined and minified versions in production with a switch in your web.config.  For a decent example, create a new MVC 4 internet web application and you can see how they build the default bundles in `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`, and how they are placed on the page in `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used pattern is to generate a constant server-side on the requested page. This way you can either use a timestamp while debugging or a "version" number relating to a specific commit / upload to purge the cache only when needed.

This can also be done by hand client side of course. For example, RequireJS provide a 'bust' option to do so.

e.g. (the example is in PHP but could be whatever really)

```
<?php define('VERSION', 34); ?>
...
<?php
function get_url_bust( $url ) {
    return $url . "?" . VERSION; // you would also like to check if the URL already contains a query etc. of course
} 
?>
...
<script src="<?php get_url_bust('something.js'); ?>">
```